# Смена изображения на HTML

Tags: html, изображения

Как реализовать механизм смены аватарки?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Нужна серверная часть.

**UPDATE** Вообщем учиться вам и учиться. Про смену аватаров судя по вашем знаниям можно будет думать где-нибудь через пол года

Comment: что нужно для серверной части?

Comment: Любая база данных + PHP.

Comment: а при помощи drag&drop что-то можно сделать?

Comment: Интерфейс, предположим, будет поддерживать drag'n'drop (html5 и куча счастья с отсутствием кроссбраузерности), где только хранить изображение-то?)